# Different Routes in Azure Functions

Tags: rest, azure, azure-functions

I am using Azure Functions and I want to create a Function that should react to multiple routes. For example "/path1/{param1}" and "/path2/xxx/{param2}" or something like this.
Does anybody know how can I implement this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use [Function Proxies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-proxies) for that.

Comment: Function Proxies are no longer supported in the Functions Runtime V4. Microsoft now recommends using Azure API Management (which costs extra).

Comment: Also FWIW a function proxy is not the same execution path as an additional route. Proxy is, as the name implies, a reverse proxy and there's both overheads and other considerations involved.

Answer (score 5):

As indicated by @Naren, the Azure functions `route` parameter is actually used as an ASP.NET route in the backend.  This means that we can also take advantage of optional parameters to provide essentially the same behavior that you want.  This is a useful alternative for a variety of things if you don't want to use Function Proxies.

Set the route to:

`/{path:regex(^path[12]$)}/{param1}/{param2?}`

Because `param2` is optional, if you call `/path2/blah` you will just get `null` for the value of `param2`.  To ensure that only xxx can be used for `param1` when `path == "path1"`, you can just do a simple check in your code.

Comment: Very nice, but missed a closing bracket
 "{path:regex(^path[12]$)}/{param1?}/{param2?}",

Comment: Thanks @Chemss-EddineBenHassine, fixed!

Answer (score 3):

Azure Functions only allow you to map a single route to a function. However the route can contain a regex. It would give you a little flexibility. You can find more information on it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#constraints).

Easier and more flexible way to do it would through be [Function Proxies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-proxies).