# Is it possible to specify route as an empty string in Azure function for Python?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I try to have a "vanilla path" in my API. I've tried to decorate my function by each of the following.

```
@app.route(route="")

@app.route(route=None)

@app.route()

@app.route(route="/")
```

It's not of interest to modify the route using `function.json` and changing the base route from a central point. Googling it provided the solution based on manipulating that file, [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45357825/different-routes-in-azure-functions). However, I wish to be able to have a route parameter not amending the base path.

If it's not possible, I wonder what the technical reason behind it is.

Answer (score -1):

Specifying an empty string as a route directly in the `@app.route()` decorator is not supported to avoid ambiguity and maintain clarity in URL patterns within Azure Functions.

I tried the below codes to trigger a function with route.

**Code-1 :**

```py
import azure.functions as func

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    path = req.route_params.get('path') or ''

    if path == '':
        return func.HttpResponse("Hello, Azure Functions with Flask! (Default route)")
    elif path == 'HttpTrigger1':
        return func.HttpResponse("Hello, Azure Functions with Flask! (HttpTrigger1 route)")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse("404 Not Found", status_code=404)
```

**Output  :**

It ran successfully as below.

```py
Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.5030 Commit hash: N/A  (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.15.2.20177

Functions:

        HttpTrigger1: [GET,POST] http://localhost:7071/api/HttpTrigger1

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-01-17T12:21:35.584Z] Worker process started and initialized.
[2024-01-17T12:21:42.457Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '00000000000xxxxxxx'.
[2024-01-17T12:21:44.498Z] Executing 'Functions.HttpTrigger1' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=40055983xxxxxxx)        
[2024-01-17T12:21:44.650Z] Executed 'Functions.HttpTrigger1' (Succeeded, Id=40055983xxxxxxxxx, Duration=179ms)
```

[image]

**Output at browser :**

```
http://localhost:7071/api/HttpTrigger1

Hello, Azure Functions with Flask! (Default route)
```

[image]

**Code-2 :**

```py
import azure.functions as func

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    return func.WsgiMiddleware(create_app()).handle(req)
    
def create_app():
    from flask import Flask
    app = Flask(__name__)
    
    @app.route('/api/HttpTrigger1')
    def home():
        return "Hello, Azure Functions with Flask!"

    return app
```

**Output :**

It ran successfully as below.

```py
Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.5030 Commit hash: N/A  (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.15.2.20177

Functions:

        HttpTrigger1: [GET,POST] http://localhost:7071/api/HttpTrigger1

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-01-17T11:24:21.756Z] Worker process started and initialized.
[2024-01-17T11:24:28.041Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000xxxxxxx'.
[2024-01-17T11:24:48.147Z] Executing 'Functions.HttpTrigger1' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=c568c523xxxxxx)        
[2024-01-17T11:24:48.562Z] Executed 'Functions.HttpTrigger1' (Succeeded, Id=c568c523xxxxxxxx, Duration=440ms)
```

[image]

**Output at browser :**

```
http://localhost:7071/api/HttpTrigger1

Hello, Azure Functions with Flask!
```

[image]